# Looking for a way to partition date on a monthly basis in Clojure

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

Want to split a date range into monthly chunks.

example Input -   `[10/20/2019 - 12/20/2019]`

example output -  `{ [10/20/2019 10/31/2019]  [11/01/2019 11/30/2019]  [12/012019 12/20/2019] }`

Thank you

Comment: trying with this.  https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time#clj-timeperiodic . Did not get desired results yet

Comment: this question was specific enough to attract a correct answer, it should not be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a simple draft of what you can do (with java interop, no external libs):

first of all let's make an iteration by month, starting with the specified one:

```
(defn by-month [[mm yyyy]]
  (iterate #(.plusMonths % 1)
           (java.time.YearMonth/of yyyy mm))) 

user> (take 4 (by-month [10 2019]))
;;=> (#object[java.time.YearMonth 0x62fc8302 "2019-10"]
;;    #object[java.time.YearMonth 0x1a7bc211 "2019-11"]
;;    #object[java.time.YearMonth 0x6a466e83 "2019-12"]
;;    #object[java.time.YearMonth 0x652ac30f "2020-01"])
```

then get start and end date for each YearMonth:

```
(defn start-end [^java.time.YearMonth ym]
  [(.atDay ym 1) (.atEndOfMonth ym)])

;;=> ([#object[java.time.LocalDate 0xe880abb "2019-10-01"]
;;     #object[java.time.LocalDate 0x54aadf50 "2019-10-31"]]
;;    [#object[java.time.LocalDate 0x14c1b42d "2019-11-01"]
;;     #object[java.time.LocalDate 0x32d0a22c "2019-11-30"]])
```

now, wrap it up in a function of ranges by your input dates:

```
(defn day-range [[mm1 dd1 yyyy1] [mm2 dd2 yyyy2]]
  (let [start (java.time.LocalDate/of yyyy1 mm1 dd1)
        end (java.time.LocalDate/of yyyy2 mm2 dd2)
        internal (->> [mm1 yyyy1]
                      by-month
                      (mapcat start-end)                     
                      (drop 1)
                      (take-while #(neg? (compare % end))))]
    (partition 2 `(~start ~@internal ~end))))

user> (day-range [10 20 2019] [12 20 2019])
;;=> ((#object[java.time.LocalDate 0x6a8f92f2 "2019-10-20"]
;;     #object[java.time.LocalDate 0x10135df3 "2019-10-31"])
;;    (#object[java.time.LocalDate 0x576bcff7 "2019-11-01"]
;;     #object[java.time.LocalDate 0x7b5ed908 "2019-11-30"])
;;    (#object[java.time.LocalDate 0x6b2117a9 "2019-12-01"]
;;     #object[java.time.LocalDate 0x57bf0864 "2019-12-20"]))
```

now you can postprocess each start-end pair as you need:

```
(map (fn [[^java.time.LocalDate start ^java.time.LocalDate end]]
       (let [fmt (java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter/ofPattern "MM/dd/yyyy")]
         [(.format start fmt) (.format end fmt)]))
     (day-range [10 20 2019] [12 20 2019]))

;;=> (["10/20/2019" "10/31/2019"]
;;    ["11/01/2019" "11/30/2019"]
;;    ["12/01/2019" "12/20/2019"])
```

another way is to iterate by day, and then partition by [month year], collecting first-last afterwards:

```
(defn ranges [[mm1 dd1 yyyy1] [mm2 dd2 yyyy2]]
  (let [start (java.time.LocalDate/of yyyy1 mm1 dd1)
        end (java.time.LocalDate/of yyyy2 mm2 dd2)]
    (->> start
         (iterate (fn [^java.time.LocalDate curr] (.plusDays curr 1)))         
         (take-while (fn [^java.time.LocalDate dt] (not (pos? (compare dt end)))))
         (partition-by (fn [^java.time.LocalDate dt] [(.getMonthValue dt) (.getYear dt)]))
         (map (juxt first last)))))

user> (ranges [10 20 2019] [12 20 2019])
;;=> ([#object[java.time.LocalDate 0x383f6a9e "2019-10-20"]
;;     #object[java.time.LocalDate 0x2ca14c39 "2019-10-31"]]
;;    [#object[java.time.LocalDate 0x74d1974 "2019-11-01"]
;;     #object[java.time.LocalDate 0x5f6c16cc "2019-11-30"]]
;;    [#object[java.time.LocalDate 0x74f63a42 "2019-12-01"]
;;     #object[java.time.LocalDate 0x4b90c388 "2019-12-20"]])
```

which produces some unneeded intermediate vals, but also gives you a way to split ranges however you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`java-time`](https://github.com/dm3/clojure.java-time):

```clj
(refer-clojure :exclude [range iterate format max min])
(use 'java-time)

(->> (iterate plus (local-date 2019 10 20) (days 1))
     (take-while #(before? % (local-date 2019 12 21)))
     (partition-by month)
     (map (fn [dates] [(first dates) (last dates)])))
```

Output:

```
([#object[java.time.LocalDate 0x26c16faf "2019-10-20"]
  #object[java.time.LocalDate 0x4113c834 "2019-10-31"]]
 [#object[java.time.LocalDate 0x7d0a5212 "2019-11-01"]
  #object[java.time.LocalDate 0x249fe02f "2019-11-30"]]
 [#object[java.time.LocalDate 0x7345f070 "2019-12-01"]
  #object[java.time.LocalDate 0x26d66577 "2019-12-20"]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Straight Java interop is the way to go here:

```
  (let [start-ld  (LocalDate/parse "2019-10-20")
        start-bom (.with start-ld (TemporalAdjusters/firstDayOfMonth))
        start-eom (.with start-ld (TemporalAdjusters/lastDayOfMonth))]

start-bom => #object[java.time.LocalDate 0x1a69aaa8 "2019-10-01"]
start-eom => #object[java.time.LocalDate 0x329970b5 "2019-10-31"]
```

You can increment the month like so:

```
        next-bom  (.plusMonths start-bom 1)
```

to get

```
next-bom => #object[java.time.LocalDate 0x21ced418 "2019-11-01"]
```

and then you can write a loop.